# Drupal 7 + Services 3 : anonymous user can't access user/register endpoint (401 access denied)

Tags: 7, users, services

I'm using Services for providing an external webapp to register new user to the Drupal server.

I'm able to login from the webapp, create node and post comment.

But I can't have access to user registration.

My endpoint is configured and got all CRUD functionnality for user checked.

But when I try to acces it : http://localhost/rest/user/register

I got a 401 : ["Access denied for user anonymous"]

I guess I'm missing sone permissions, but I can't figure out which one ?

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

nieud

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently the 401 is a false error message.

I had an error in the data structure I posted to user/register, when I fixed it the 401 disappeared.

I still have an error on my user registration but this is now a 500.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Configuration -> People -> Account settings** and verify that `Visitors` or `Visitors, but administrator approval is required` is selected for the **Who can register accounts** setting. This page can be reached at:

```
admin/config/people/accounts
```

After that, try the **Rebuild permissions** link located under **Reports -> Status report**. This page can be reached at:

```
admin/reports/status
```

And of course flush all of Drupal's caches after enabling/disabling Service Resources and endpoints.

Comment: Hello Tyler, and thanks for your answer. But all these settings were allready checked. 

Sorry I forgot to mention that.